# How to composite muliple existing actions into one in play

Tags: playframework, play-slick

I have a web needs both auth and also access database, there are 2 plugin needed, one is socialsecure and another one is play-sclick. To use socialsecure, I need to use action of SecuredAction, and to use click, I need to use DBAction, then the problem is how to composite both SecuredAction  and DBAction?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to achieve that with Play's action composition, see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.4/ScalaActionsComposition. Already seen that?